# How to decrease the MDCTextField height in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, height

i am using [material-components-ios](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios) pod for textfield

so i have installed `pod 'MaterialComponents/TextFields'` in my project

**and in storyboard for `serviceTitleTextField` i have given height 30**. but still its coming big height

code:

```
import MaterialComponents

class PageContentViewController: UIViewController {
    
@IBOutlet weak var serviceTitleTextField: MDCTextField!

private var titleTextfieldeController: MDCTextInputControllerOutlined?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()  

titleTextfieldeController = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: serviceTitleTextField)
titleTextfieldeController?.floatingPlaceholderActiveColor = .darkGray

 }
```

here the texfield height is too big. **how to show 30 height for textfield?**

output:

[image]